# PowerPoint startup error - it's trying to find a non-existant add-in

Tags: registry, powerpoint, add-in, powerpoint-addins

I need help figuring out how to stop a startup error message.

(Win10/11; PPT365 64-bit)

PowerPoint startup displays an error because it's trying to find a NON-EXISTANT add-in (normal add-in; not a Com).

**"Sorry, for some reason PowerPoint couldn't load the C:\SN^BTS2\PPAM\aic_0116.ppam add-in."**

The user clicks OK then PPT starts normally, including loading the real add-in it is supposed to start.

The computer previously ran the add-in in the error message. As the name indicates, it was version 116. But it was changed to a new version (v118). The ppam's were swapped via normal methods – v116 was removed in the PPT add-in list; closed/reopened PPT to ensure it's gone; closed PPT; in our add-in host folder (C:\SN^BTS2\PPAM), we removed the v116 ppam and placed v118 ppam there; opened PPT and added the v118 add-in; it ran fine.

But when we closed/reopened PPT, it gave us the error message above.

One version or another, over 10k users run this add-in that I created for the company, and it's run flawlessly for 18 years. It's updated often, hence the version number at the end of the file name. Nothing in this add-in changes except maybe a URL addy it communicates with.

I checked the registry key for the add-in and it was correctly entered for v118. An add-in key for v116 does not exist. (Users have only 16.0 in the registry.) I even searched the entire registry for this add-in name. There was nothing except some history and such, but nothing to launch it.

With one user, I successfully resolved this by opening the v118 add-in key; doing nothing to it, and closing it. Then I refreshed the registry (F5). But this did not work with other users.

It feels like something is stuck in memory. I cleared temp files for PPT. I can't for Windows due to risks.

As a test, I removed the v118 add-in from the add-in list; closed PPT; opened the ppam host folder; changed the ppam name of 118 that was there to 116; opened PPT; no more error. PPT found what it was looking for. But when I removed v116 from the add-in list and changed the file name back to 118; PPT gave the same error.

- The address shown in the error has the v118 ppam in it, not the v116.
- The v116 still shows up unchecked in the add-in list in PPT (along with the v118 but is blocked by the v116 error).
- We remove the v116 from the list, and it returns on the next PPT startup along with the error.
- The registry does NOT have an add-in key to start v116; just v118.
- Searching the registry, it has no reference to the v116 (except in non-vital history and such).
- We tried removing all add-ins, but no joy. It still wants v116.
- I renamed the v118 file to v116, and PPT liked that. No error. (But we must change numbers back.)

**PPT will not stop looking for v116 add-in which does not exist in the folder or in the registry.**

Any help or leads is appreciated.

Thanks,

Mel Turco